# How to change text of a widget depend on condition?

Tags: widgets, text

I have text widget with default ads on it ( google ads for example ).

Sometime, depend on condition like location, time, I need to change the default ads from code, just temporary only.

Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: Have you looked into [shortcodes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API)?

Comment: I looked into add_filter and widget_text work perfectly, but you have to know exactly which widget to change, Thank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be pretty easy to alter the text for the Core text widget via the [`widget_text`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.3.1/src/wp-includes/default-widgets.php#L590) filter:

```
function conditional_text_widget_wpse_207957($text) {
  if (is_single()) {
    $text = "Whoa, d00d! I'm single";
  }
  return $text;
}
add_filter('widget_text','conditional_text_widget_wpse_207957');
```

You do not specify what conditions you need exactly, nor provide any detail about the changes you need.

Comment: Thank for the help. The code work perfectly, I used something like this for the condition, using preg_match to know exactly which widget I modify:

<code>
function conditional_text_widget_wpse_207957($text) {
  if (preg_match( $found, $replace, $text )) {
    $text = "Whoa, d00d! I'm single";
  }
  return $text;
}
add_filter('widget_text','conditional_text_widget_wpse_207957');

</code>